# How can malloc() throw an Access violation error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc

What can be the reasons that make `malloc()`, throw an Access violation error? I fear that it is allocating on a corrupted space memory (hard to debug). But are there, others reasons possible? Thanks.

As you see on the picture, the size value is correct.

[image: example]

Comment: One reason would be a bug somewhere in your code corrupted the heap, and `malloc()` blew up due to the corrupted heap. P.S. Do not use `malloc()` in C++ code.

Comment: That's what I fear. It's not my code, it's the Windows's implementation of the standard lib.

Comment: Certainly a bug in a Windows library is a possibility. But the Windows library is not going to execute itself, on its own volition. Your own code is likely linking and using it. So, the bug is still likely to be in your own code.

Comment: Heap corruption usually manifests long after it occurred, and in an unrelated piece of code. It's nasty this way. So, dollars to donuts, the bug is somewhere in your code, and possibly not anywhere near the code that's failing.

Comment: @Mr G0z: Heap integrity was destroyed by *your* code. After that any code can crash, including standard library code. This is what you are observing. There's no point in looking at the code you posted in your screenshot. It is not to blame in this case.

Comment: `That's what I fear. It's not my code, it's the Windows's implementation of the standard lib.` Yeah. No. In 9999/10000 cases it is a bug in your code. Not the OS. Not the framework you are using. You should always assume it is your fault and only blame someone else once you are left with no other possibility (or you can prove it via an isolated test)

Comment: Oh sorry I was not clear. That was an answer to @Sam Varshavchik. What I meant is that the Windows's implementation of the standard lib make calls to `malloc()` when using the `new` operator. Of course the bug is not related to the standard lib. The goal of the picture was just to illustrate the issue, not accuse. (To be more accurate, the demo delivered with a "library" (a teacher's lib) that I use, crashes randomly too. In release my code and the demo fail instantly on the first call).

Comment: A C++ library can certainly use `malloc()` as part of its `new` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

some bug code had destroied the heap memory, and then you called an memory operation, exception occurred.  you can try a tool called Application Verifier, which can help you to find the bug.